# Use loop on sql "UPDATE" for setting value

Tags: php, mysqli

So, I'm learning about how to update a database using loop.
I have a table with field names like "id", "nh1", "nh2", "nh3".

Here's the example of input boxes:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='input$i'>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

What I'm trying to do is that I want to update my database using loop, Like:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    ${'NH'.$i} = $_POST['input'.$i];
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $q = mysqli_query("update myTable set nh$i=${'NH'.$i} where id=1");
}
```

Is it even possible? Or is there any other way to use it correctly?

Hope I made my question clear.

Comment: Have you tried it? If it doesn't work correctly what errors are you getting? Make sure you have error reporting turned on too `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: Don't concatenate in strings. `mysqli_query` requires 2 parameters the first must be the connection. You should parameterize. This could be written as 1 query.

Comment: You probably would have been better off with the HTML syntax `name="input[]"`

Comment: @user3783243 My bad. I'll include the connection manually in my code.

Comment: @Dave I have. It doesn't work unfortunately. About the error report, i doesn't give me anything. :(

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version uses both prepared statements as well as building a single SQL statement.  I've added code in the comments to help...

```
// Values used to bind to prepare
$binds = [];
// The types of the binds
$types = "";
// The SQL statement
$update = "update myTable set ";
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    // If this input is set
    if ( isset($_POST['input'.$i])) {
        // Store it in the array
        $binds[] = $_POST['input'.$i];
        // Add in part of SQL - e.g. nh1 = ?,
        $update .= "nh$i = ?,";
        // Add type of parameter (string)
        $types .= "s";
    }
}
// Add where clause (remove trialing comma from list of fields to update
$update = substr ($update, 0, -1)." where id=1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($update);
// Bind the variables
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$binds );
$stmt->execute();
```

The statement it builds would be something like...

```
update myTable set nh1 = ?,nh3 = ? where id=1
```

with the data to bind shown below, so each of these elements will be put in place of the corresponding placeholder (the `?`) in the SQL.

```
Array
(
    [0] => value for input 1
    [1] => value for input 3
)
```

Comment: @Dharman, if you prefer code to done differently then by all means add a comment, but please don't change answers to your preference of coding.